# Updating highcharts.js data on a 'stacked columns' chart : update() or setData()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I've been trying to update a chart's data and, after trying out highchart's methods 'setData' and 'update', I've found they behave differently (at least in this case).

In other questions/answers, it seems that setData is preferred, and even in the docs, it says that update is 'more performance expensive' than setData... But I can't achieve the same results. What's the difference between these 2 methods?

What I'm doing:
1. get data from JSON, map the data to get 'categories' and 'series' arrays. I end up with something like this:

```
//categories
var categoriesFromJSON = ["source 1", "source 2"];
```

and

```
var initialSeriesFromJSON = [
    {name: "Data 1", data: [1000, 800]},
    {name: "Data 2", data: [800, 648]},
    {name: "Data 3", data: [600, 534]},
    {name: "Data 4", data: [400, 213]},
];
```

2. build a 'stacked columns' chart.
3. poll the server...
4. If there's updated data, update the chart.

using update:

```
var chart = $('#graph').highcharts();
    $.each(updatedSeriesFromJSON, function(key, val){
        chart.series[key].update(val, false);
    });
    chart.redraw();
```

using setData:

```
var chart = $('#graph').highcharts();
    $.each(updatedSeriesFromJSON, function(key, val){
        chart.series[key].setData(val, false, true, false);
    });       
    chart.redraw();
```

Here's a JSFIDDLE showing both behaviours
[https://jsfiddle.net/brainofjon/1vveL1gL/](http://jsfiddle.net/brainofjon/1vveL1gL/1/)

In this example, update does the job... but I was wondering why I can't do the same using setData. Any input will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: setData() only affects the data object of the given series. Hence the name.  update() allows you to update all of the properties of a series object (eg color, marker settings, name, id, index, etc) for the specified series..

Comment: Hi @jlbriggs, thanks for replying. I get what you say, so setData would be more appropriate in this case... but I can get it to work as I want (which happens when using update). Maybe I'm missing somtething. BTW, the jsfiddle link was wrong, I updated it.

Comment: in your fiddle, the setData method does not work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of each function is different, and so the behavior is different.

Using your example, you are trying to use `setData()` on your series, sending the entire series object as the data, which is why it fails - you need to send only the data when using `setData()`, not the full series object.

Updated example using your set up:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/rf9v6z9m/

The only important part of the change is here:

```
//Update chart using 'setData()'
$('button#setData').click(function(){
    $.each(updatedSeriesFromJSON, function(key, val){
        chart.series[key].setData(**val.data**);
    });       
});
```

The `setData(val)` becomes `setData(val.data)`, so that you are only sending the data object, and not the entire series object.

This will obviously work faster, because you are only editing the data and not the entire series, whereas `series.update()` scraps the entire series object and rebuilds it with the series options that you send it.

Comment: @jibriggs please help me with my problem about highchart http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647911/highchart-stacked-bar-plotting-data-doesnt-work-by-javascript