# highchart stacked bar plotting data doesn't work by javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, highcharts

why is this, i am having a trouble in plotting a data in bar highchart. I am using this `chart.series[i].addPoint(data[i]['total_check']);` but when i alert `alert(data[i]['total_check']);` there are values, but when i go plot it in barchart, it doesn't appear. I am wondering if my code is in a wrong way ? . 
Here is my code where i plot the points from barchart :

```
function getbarseries(month) {
    $.ajax({
      url: siteurl+"patients_report/bardataclinic/"+month,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
           for(var i in data) {
               chart.series[i].addPoint(data[i]['total_check']);
               //alert(data[i]['total_check']);
           }
        }
    });
}
```

i am plotting a chart by doing a recursive way , so the main part of my code is this :

```
function getbarxAxis() {
 $.ajax({
   url: siteurl+"patients_report/bardata_date",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "JSON",
   success: function(data) {
     var categories = new Array();
     for (var i in data) {
       categories.push(data[i]["datemonths"]);
     }
    loadChart(categories);
    getallclinics();
    var arrayLength = categories.length;
    for(var loop = 0;loop<arrayLength;loop++) {
        getbarseries(categories[loop]);
    }

   }
 });
}
```

i am making a dynamic bar highchart thats why first, i am getting categories (months) with query to the function that i use `loadChart(categories);` after i plotted the categories,

```
function loadChart(categories) {
   chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: categories
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Detailed patient per clinic'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
    }
});
}
```

after i plotted the categories, next within it is the series data name, where i also make a new function to query in my database and plot all the data series names, the function named : `getallclinics();`
the fullcode of getallclinics function is this:

```
function getallclinics() {
   $.ajax ({
          url: siteurl+"patients_report/seriesclinics",
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(data) {
            for(var i in data) {
              chart.addSeries({
                  name: data[i]['clinic_name']
              });
            }
          }
   });
}
```

after getting the clinics, the last part is what i've got trouble, where i want to plot the data from the series name declared, so the code above which is the `getbarseries` is what i am having trouble, where i plot there `chart.series[i].addPoint(data[i]['total_check']);`

Full code of my getbarseries:

```
function getbarseries(month) {
    $.ajax({
      url: siteurl+"patients_report/bardataclinic/"+month,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
           for(var i in data) {
               chart.series[i].addPoint(data[i]['total_check']);
               //alert(data[i]['total_check']);
           }
        }
    });
}
```

what i did there was every month from the function getbarseries(month), i got my months with a total checkup :
here is the result from my console since i have only two returned months from my categories , then i have two recursive loops for `getbarseries` function

first recursive loop: `[{"clinic_name":"Clinic 1","total_check":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 2","total_check":"1"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 3","total_check":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 4","total_check":"0"}]`

second recursive loop: `[{"clinic_name":"Clinic 1","total_check":"2"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 2","total_check":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 3","total_check":"0"},{"clinic_name":"Clinic 4","total_check":"0"}]`

Comment: any answers pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you data seem to be strings, you need to parse them to be numbers.

You can use this: [Convert argument to number](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_number.asp)

```
function getbarseries(month) {
    $.ajax({
      url: siteurl+"patients_report/bardataclinic/"+month,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
           for(var i in data) {
               chart.series[i].addPoint(Number(data[i]['total_check']));
           }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thankssssss sir, .. can you trace my code? is there anything that other instances that it will be error?

Comment: if the code does what you want it to do, then there is a chance that it is ok.   For code reviews it is better to use [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) resource.